# Getting jitter to show up in ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm trying to stand up a plotly scatter plot with factor axes, adding a jitter to the values for readability.

I'm able to get the wanted effect in ggplot2, but when I try to wrap that with plotly the jitter doesn't make it. Any way to get this to work?

An example of what's going on. g below looks right, but p then loses the jitter.

```
data<-data.frame(cbind(
  sample(c('level 1', 'level 2', 'level 3'), 100, replace = TRUE),
  sample(c('level 1', 'level 2', 'level 3', 'level 4'), 100, replace = TRUE)))

names(data)<-c('factor1', 'factor2')

g <- ggplot(data, aes(x=factor1, y=factor2)) 
g <- g + geom_point(position = position_jitter(w = 0.2,h = 0.2))
#g <- g + geom_jitter(width = .2, height = .2)
g <- g +xlab('Category One')
g <- g +ylab('Category Two')

g

p <- ggplotly(g)
p
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is maybe a work around. Replace your factor by integer, and relabel after.

```
data<-data.frame(cbind(
    sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE),
    sample(1:4, 100, replace = TRUE)))

names(data)<-c('factor1', 'factor2')

g <- ggplot(data, aes(x=factor1, y=factor2)) 
g <- g + geom_point(position = position_jitter(w = 0.2,h = 0.2)) + scale_x_continuous("Factor 1", breaks = c(1,2,3)) + scale_y_continuous("Factor 2", breaks = c(1,2,3,4))
ggplotly(g)
```

relabel x and y ticks

```
x <- list(
  tickprefix = "Level"
)

y <- list(
  tickprefix = "Level"
)

g %>% layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y)
```

[image]

Comment: That's a nice thought! Ultimately, however, the hope is to be able to use non-numeric factor names as levels so they correspond to, say, survey responses like "Disagree Strongly, "Disagree", "Neutral", etc....is there a way to further customize tick prefixes to change by tick?

Comment: you did not say that in your post!

Comment: You're right! But you also got me to a solution using the same approach and ticktext instead of tickprefix.

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
data<-data.frame(cbind(
  sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE),
  sample(1:4, 100, replace = TRUE)))

names(data)<-c('factor1', 'factor2')

g <- ggplot(data, aes(x=factor1, y=factor2)) 
g <- g + geom_point(position = position_jitter(w = 0.2,h = 0.2)) + scale_x_continuous("Factor 1", breaks = c(1,2,3)) + scale_y_continuous("Factor 2", breaks = c(1,2,3,4))
p <- ggplotly(g)

x <- list(title = "Category One",tickmode = "array",tickvals = c(1,2,3) , ticktext = c("A", "B", "C"))
y <- list(title = "Category Two",tickmode = "array",tickvals = c(1,2,3,4) , ticktext = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))

p <- p %>% layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y)
p
```